# Refreshing variable just before invoking it?

Tags: bash, variables, backup, tar, xz

I have some easy backup script to tar, xz and save to SMB share some folders and want to use variable ($invocation) for a part of the command.

Unfortunately, when script runs it remembers that the variable $location is empty and a result of it is no backup

(`xz: /mnt/backupMatrix//2020-06-05T00-27.tar.xz: No such file or directory`).

I do know why it's not working, but how to do it correctly?
How to "reload" variable $invocation (with freshly set $location) just before it's launch, WITHOUT hardcoding whole invocation to the function?

Code below.

```
#! /bin/bash
invocation="xz --threads=8 -z -9 -v -v - > /mnt/backupMatrix/$location/$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M).tar.xz"

function mcuser2
{
    #backup mcuser2
    location="mcuser2"
    echo "setting var location to: $location"
    echo "Stopping minecraft2.service"
    sudo systemctl stop minecraft2.service
    echo "Stopped minecraft2.service"
    echo "Starting taring mcuser2"

    # --exclude='/home/mcuser2/world'
    tar cpf - --exclude='/home/mcuser2/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles' /home/mcuser2/ | $invocation

    echo "Completed taring mcuser2"
    echo "starting minecraft2.service"
    sudo systemctl start minecraft2.service
    echo "started successfully minecraft2.service"
}

case "$1" in
    mcuser2)
        mcuser2
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: FYI I replaced your backticks around the `date` command with `$()`.

Comment: You could use `tar -Jcpf ...`.  The `-J` option applies `xz` on the tar automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since you set `location` unconditionally in the function, the simplest approach is to move that line from the function and place it before you set `invocation`.

An alternative is to use more variables:

```
: "${XZ:=xz}"
: "${XZOPTIONS:=--threads=8 -z -9 -v -v -}"
: "${TSTAMP:=$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M)}"
: "${BASEDIR:=/mnt/backupMatrix}"
: "${TAR:=tar}"
: "${TAROPTIONS:=-cpf -}"

STARTDIR="/home/mcuser2"     # $HOME?
EXCLUDE="--exclude=$STARTDIR/plugins/dynmap/web/tiles"

function mcuser2
{
    #backup mcuser2
    location="mcuser2"
    echo "setting var location to: $location"
    echo "Stopping minecraft2.service"
    sudo systemctl stop minecraft2.service
    echo "Stopped minecraft2.service"
    echo "Starting tarring mcuser2"

    $TAR $TAROPTIONS - "$EXCLUDE" "$STARTDIR" |
    $XZ $XZOPTIONS > "$BASEDIR/$location/$TSTAMP.tar.xz"

    echo "Completed tarring $STARTDIR"
    echo "starting minecraft2.service"
    sudo systemctl start minecraft2.service &&
    echo "started successfully minecraft2.service"
}
```

<sup>*Warning: untested shell scripting.*</sup>

I'd probably not include the full path in the archive (GNU `tar` drops the leading slash anyway); I'd `cd` to the start directory and specify `.` as the directory to be backed up — possibly use `-C "$STARTDIR"` on the `tar` command line.  That would require me to alter the exclude option too, I expect, using a relative path instead of an absolute path.

You could also think of using shell arrays for the options lists.

I'm not convinced I'd use a function in this script; it doesn't really seem to help very much.

Comment: Hi, thank's for reply. I have about 5 function like this in a script and need to change $location basing on which case I'm using. Would you recommend something different instead of functions?

Comment: You minimized the script so my analysis of the merits of a function is less relevant.  I'd expect to pass the location, and maybe a starting directory and exclusion list, as arguments to the function.  If you only stop and restart the Mine Craft service once, I'd separate that out.  Use functions to encapsulate common code; use the arguments to adapt what the function does.